# Resolve my confusion about SVN "projects" on a remote repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've been getting up to speed on SVN and have an idea of the basics. However, there's one point of confusion for me that I'd like help understanding.

I've done a bunch of reading through this great guide I found linked elsewhere on StackOverflow:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.layout

In particular, I'm taking their recommendation to arrange my repository with my 3 projects as follows:

```
\repository\projectA\trunk
\repository\projectA\branches
\repository\projectA\tags

\repository\projectB\trunk
\repository\projectB\branches
\repository\projectB\tags
```

However, my question isn't about the arrangement above as there are a hundred questions on SO concerning that already.

Instead, my question is about how remote repositories work wrt to the organization I want and how TortoiseSVN works with it.  I'm using xp-dev in particular but this question applies to the other remote SVN repositories I saw (like codesion).

I didn't see a way to create a repository, only a "project". So I'm confused between the terminology of "project" compared to the term "remote repository' as it appears as far as I"m concerned there are only "remote projects".

So given I want to arrange my repository like I described above, should I be creating **2** project on xp-dev ("projectA" and "projectB") or a single project (say "foo") with 2 sub-folders in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if this helps: a Subversion **repository** is the deamon/server process that responds to your svn client commands. Also, the whole content accessible via a single server might be regarded as the **repository**.

A **project** is nothing more than a simple folder within the whole subversion hosted content.

In facts, that's pretty much the reason why you use the layout as you described: if you want to have different branches or tags, you "copy" the whole project in a new location under the `tags` or `branches` folders, "creating" a separated project to host that separated codebase. And it's also the reason why TortoiseSVN (and any SVN client) cannot care less of your repository layout: they only need to know the absolute remote URL associated to your local files and they're absolutely fine with it.

Usually, in order to have multiple project in a single SVN repository you create a base folder per each project and then the normal layout as you already know it within, like:

```
svn_root/
   |
   |\-> projectA
   |       |
   |        \->trunk
   |        \->tags
   |        \->branches
   |
    \-> projectB
           |
            \->trunk
            \->tags
            \->branches
```

As there's no such a thing as a subversion "project" formal definition, just think of them as xp-dev logical entities and create two separated projects, one per each project you have :-)

EDIT: updated to clearly state what the suggestion is

Comment: So to be more specific, are you saying to create 2 projects on my remote repository, or a single one?

Comment: I'm saying it's best to create 2 separated projects. It makes even more sense if you're using tools such as xp-dev because "projects" are meaningful entities there, as they are used to provide management features or views on your versioned content.

Comment: While I agree that everything in this answer is true as it applies to Subversion, the OP question was asking about projects as they apply to Codesion (and other remote repositories) in particular. A project in Codesion can *contain* 1 each of Subversion/GIT/CVS repositories. After the Subversion repository is added to a Codesion project, it can then be organized into Subversion "projects" as described in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The other reply is correct. In the example you place a 'project' is just another folder.

However, let me expand it in the Codesion context as you mentioned Codesion.:

You can have one Codesion Project, with one Repository.... so you can have:
(CompanyProjectX is just a folder here)

```
MyCodesionProjectRepo
  |
  |\-> CompanyProjectA
        |
         \trunk
         \branches
         \tags
  |\-> CompanyProjectB
        |
         \trunk
         \branches
         \tags
```

Or you can also have 2 Codesion Projects (ea with it's own repo):

```
MyCodesionProjectRepoA
   |
    \trunk
    \branches
    \tags

MyCodesionProjectRepoB
   |
    \trunk
    \branches
    \tags
```

As recommended by the other answer, it's probably better to create a repository (or Codesion Project) per **your** company/organization projects

cheers!

Tona